# Blur whole background except behind transparent div?

Tags: html, css, background, blur

Take a look at the picture. I want the whole background to be blurred (like it is right now) except the area (div) marked. The div is transparent and what i want is that you can see clearly through it.

You can see here what i mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IvYB.png

Comment: Try adding a white overlay on the body with a partially transparent background. Then, make the z index of the navbar higher than the overlay. Also, stack overflow is a website to ask for help about your code, not ask for code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found!

HTML

```
<div class="bg-image"></div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/R4jk5aR.jpg");

  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```